# in Node, how to remove a substring that ends with some certain characters

Tags: node.js, string, indexof

In sourceConfigPath variable, it has a path like `"conf/test.json"`, or it might have another layer, like `"test/conf/test.json"`. I want to get the `"test.json"` part only.

I tried the indexOf function to get the position, then use either slice or substr function to get the `'test.json'` part. But it always return 0 when do `indexOf`.

Can anyone please help here? many thanks!

```
var position = sourceConfigPath.indexOf('conf');
var newsourceConfigPath = sourceConfigPath.slice(position+4);
```

Or is there any better way to do this? Many thanks!

Comment: Careful... not everyone uses forward slashes `/` in their paths...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way is to use [path.basename](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path_path_basename_path_ext)

> The path.basename() methods returns the last portion of a path,
>   similar to the Unix basename

```
const path = require('path');
const newSource = path.basename('conf/test.json'); // test.json
```

---

You can use `lastIndexOf` instead of `indexOf`, but `path.basename` is recommended.

```js
const filepath = '/path/to/file.json';

const position = filepath.lastIndexOf('/') + 1;  // +1 is to remove '/'

console.log(filepath.substr(position));
```